# creating debian squeeze bootable usb from ubuntu

Tags: bootable-media, debian-squeeze, ubuntu-14.04

Is it even possible to take a debian"squeeze" iso and make a bootable usb using "Startup disk creator" in ubuntu 14.04. If so, then I'm lost as I always get an error "GNU/Linux exception caught".

If not, how do I burn a bootable usb of debian from ubuntu ?

Comment: Why squeeze, and not wheezy?

Comment: It's a third party research library. And you know the researchers !

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything else on the USB stick?  If not, simply try `dd if=debia_iso of=/dev/usbdevice`.

The Debian isos have a [hybrid bootloader](http://joeyh.name/blog/entry/Debian_USB_install_from_hybrid_iso/) that will work as either an iso or a hard drive type tevice.